# Understanding TensorFlow model input

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, model, byte

According to the description of this TF model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VFC_wIpw4O7xBOiTgUldl79d9LA-LsnA/view the model expects an image input size of 192x192. Running a Python script to determine the TF input gets us:

```
INPUT
[  1 192 192   3]
<class 'numpy.float32'>
```

When trying to add an image input to the model I get the following error:

```
Provided data count 23040 must match the required count 442368.
```

I'm trying to understand how do I get 442368 count from a 192x192 image (what are the calculations?) and what does the input that the Python script produced means.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The input is 4d tensor which specifies you have 1 image, with 192*192 as lenght*breadth and 3 channels that are RGB. However, your second question is quite unclear. What do u mean by getting 442368 from 192*192?

Comment: Hey @AniketBote, thank you for replying. 'What do u mean by getting 442368 from 192*192?' I mean that TF model expects an input image in the size of 442368 bytes (I think at least that's what the meant in Data Count). But if each pixel has 3 channels (RGB), so 192 * 192 * 3 = 110592 bits (I think). So what is the right calculation to get 442368 byes from 192x192 image?

Comment: @AniketBote I'm super confused

Comment: consider 192*192*3 = 110592 as features instead of bytes/bits. Because the bytes/bits depend on the dtype of the image array. It's difficult to say what the model input is from the information provided. I suggest you update your question with standalone code to reproduce this error. The maximum features an image can have with size (l*b) are l * b * channels.

Comment: @AniketBote Just sent you a message over Linkedin